# Why do planets other than earth have colours?

Tags: planets, scattering, atmospheric-science

I know Mars has many red rocks and mountains. But since it does not have any atmosphere, it shouldn't have any color. So, why does it appear red?

Answer (score 5):

[Mars does have an atmosphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Mars). Iron oxide dust in the atmosphere [contributes to its redness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars#Viewing), though without this dust it would still be colored.

As a side note, our Moon has very little atmosphere. If you paint the Moon's surface pink, it'll reflect the sun's light and look pink, even without an atmosphere.

Comment: +1 Pretty much all I was about to say in a comment. Although I might have gone with a pink moon, for better contrast with the night sky. :)

Comment: Good idea. Done.

Comment: the moon is actually the color of worn asphalt.

Comment: Sorry, I just couldn't resist https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81732/FullMoon.jpg